# when i want to install yajraBox in my laravel 6.12 i am facing the follwoing error.How can i solve this problem?

Tags: laravel, datatable, installation

`C:\xampp\htdocs\PMS>composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle` Using version ^9.8 for `yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle ./composer.json` has been updated Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
    - symfony/mime v5.0.4 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.2.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/mime v5.0.4 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.2.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/mime v5.0.4 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.2.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for symfony/mime (locked at v5.0.4) -> satisfiable by symfony/mime[v5.0.4].
```

```
Installation failed, reverting `./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update your PHP to >=7.2.5 version. You have 7.2.0